# Data Binding with srcCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-databinding

I'm using the new vector drawable support in Support Lib v23.2 with app:srcCompat & trying to set its drawable via data binding.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="mediaPojo"
        type="in.ishaan.pika.data_binding.MediaPojo"/>
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <VideoView
        ... />

    <ImageView
        ...
        app:srcCompat="@{mediaPojo.isPlaying ? @drawable/ic_pause_24dp : @drawable/ic_play_arrow_24dp}"
    />

    <ProgressBar
        .../>
</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

On trying to build, studio throws:

> Error:(33, 30) Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:srcCompat' with parameter type android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.

Comment: Did you include the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` attribute on the root element of your layout ?

Comment: @PaulDS yep, let me update the question with full layout

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can simply use ***android:src*** attribute instead compat attribute when you set vector resource by DataBinding.

DataBinding library generates class that execute *setImageResource* method at runtime.

```
<ImageView
        ...
        android:src="@{@drawable/your_drawable}"
/>
```

According to http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html *setImageResource* method can be used at runtime on older system versions without any additional changes.

If you would like to use *app:srcCompat* attribute. You must define @BindingMethods annotation which connects attribute with appropriate setter from ImageView. For example in your Activity or Fragment add.

```
@BindingMethods({
    @BindingMethod(type = android.widget.ImageView.class,
            attribute = "app:srcCompat",
            method = "setImageDrawable") })
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // your activity body here

}
```

Comment: _"DataBinding library generates class that execute setImageResource method at runtime."_

Are you sure about this? You cannot open the binding classes so how do we be sure?

Comment: I checked two things: 

1. Displaying vector drawable on pre lolipop devices when using android:src attribute and DataBinding (It displays without exception)

2. One of software engeeniers working in Google says here (in  Expression Tree (8:01) section)  https://realm.io/news/data-binding-android-boyar-mount/ about matching src attribute with setImageResource method

Comment: Moreover you can try to find in your code ImageViewBindingAdapter. It is adapter from DataBinding library used to bind ImageView. In generated code you can find references to this adapter. 

You can open generated classes using NotePad++ for example :) Because Android Studio opens xml layout by default. 
They are stored in app\build\intermediates\classes\your\package\name\databinding

Comment: I noticed that in fact DataBinding generates code that uses setImageDrawable + getDrawableFromResource method :) But it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the research on this :)

Comment: This worked after I added `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);` in the activity which uses vector resources.

Comment: I was forget to add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in gradle so the problem still appear to me and when add it fix my problem and work, thank you .

Comment: This will only work after calling `AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);`. And it does not use `setImageResource`. These should be mentioned.

Answer (score 15):

You may have to resort to using a binding adapter with a method signature similar to the following:

```
@BindingAdapter("app:srcCompat")
public static void bindSrcCompat(ImageView imageView, Drawable drawable){
    // Your setter code goes here, like setDrawable or similar
}
```

Here is the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter.html

Comment: I had to remove the `app:` part to get it to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The proposed answers mainly worked for me but I also needed to add this line in my Application:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

Doing so allows me to use vector drawables in older versions without needing to worry about compat classes or attributes

Comment: Do keep in mind that using this flag causes memory issues (https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88)

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use srcCompat and also need to set a tint via xml on your drawables the easiest way is to use android.support.v7.widget.**AppCompatImageView**

And then **android:tint** and **app:srcCompat** work just fine.

note: for some reason unknown to me in fragment layouts using ImageView works fine. Reverting to AppCompatImageView is only necessary in activity layouts.